# Unity3D FollowCam not following player vehicle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a garage that gives the option for the player to select the car he wants to take to the race, the problem is the camera doesn't attach to the when it's sent.

The follow camera is using the standard unity assets.

Garage code(This code loads the car into the map):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class LoadCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] characterPrefabs;
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    //public TMP_Text label;

    void Start()
    {
        int selectedCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedCharacter");
        GameObject prefab = characterPrefabs[selectedCharacter];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        //label.text = prefab.name;
    }
}
```

Camera code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR

#endif

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Cameras
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class AutoCam : PivotBasedCameraRig
    {
        [SerializeField] private float m_MoveSpeed = 3; // How fast the rig will move to keep up with target's position
        [SerializeField] private float m_TurnSpeed = 1; // How fast the rig will turn to keep up with target's rotation
        [SerializeField] private float m_RollSpeed = 0.2f;// How fast the rig will roll (around Z axis) to match target's roll.
        [SerializeField] private bool m_FollowVelocity = false;// Whether the rig will rotate in the direction of the target's velocity.
        [SerializeField] private bool m_FollowTilt = true; // Whether the rig will tilt (around X axis) with the target.
        [SerializeField] private float m_SpinTurnLimit = 90;// The threshold beyond which the camera stops following the target's rotation. (used in situations where a car spins out, for example)
        [SerializeField] private float m_TargetVelocityLowerLimit = 4f;// the minimum velocity above which the camera turns towards the object's velocity. Below this we use the object's forward direction.
        [SerializeField] private float m_SmoothTurnTime = 0.2f; // the smoothing for the camera's rotation

        private float m_LastFlatAngle; // The relative angle of the target and the rig from the previous frame.
        private float m_CurrentTurnAmount; // How much to turn the camera
        private float m_TurnSpeedVelocityChange; // The change in the turn speed velocity
        private Vector3 m_RollUp = Vector3.up;// The roll of the camera around the z axis ( generally this will always just be up )


        protected override void FollowTarget(float deltaTime)
        {
            // if no target, or no time passed then we quit early, as there is nothing to do
            if (!(deltaTime > 0) || m_Target == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // initialise some vars, we'll be modifying these in a moment
            var targetForward = m_Target.forward;
            var targetUp = m_Target.up;

            if (m_FollowVelocity && Application.isPlaying)
            {
                // in follow velocity mode, the camera's rotation is aligned towards the object's velocity direction
                // but only if the object is traveling faster than a given threshold.

                if (targetRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > m_TargetVelocityLowerLimit)
                {
                    // velocity is high enough, so we'll use the target's velocty
                    targetForward = targetRigidbody.velocity.normalized;
                    targetUp = Vector3.up;
                }
                else
                {
                    targetUp = Vector3.up;
                }
                m_CurrentTurnAmount = Mathf.SmoothDamp(m_CurrentTurnAmount, 1, ref m_TurnSpeedVelocityChange, m_SmoothTurnTime);
            }
            else
            {
                // we're in 'follow rotation' mode, where the camera rig's rotation follows the object's rotation.

                // This section allows the camera to stop following the target's rotation when the target is spinning too fast.
                // eg when a car has been knocked into a spin. The camera will resume following the rotation
                // of the target when the target's angular velocity slows below the threshold.
                var currentFlatAngle = Mathf.Atan2(targetForward.x, targetForward.z)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                if (m_SpinTurnLimit > 0)
                {
                    var targetSpinSpeed = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.DeltaAngle(m_LastFlatAngle, currentFlatAngle))/deltaTime;
                    var desiredTurnAmount = Mathf.InverseLerp(m_SpinTurnLimit, m_SpinTurnLimit*0.75f, targetSpinSpeed);
                    var turnReactSpeed = (m_CurrentTurnAmount > desiredTurnAmount ? .1f : 1f);
                    if (Application.isPlaying)
                    {
                        m_CurrentTurnAmount = Mathf.SmoothDamp(m_CurrentTurnAmount, desiredTurnAmount,
                                                             ref m_TurnSpeedVelocityChange, turnReactSpeed);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // for editor mode, smoothdamp won't work because it uses deltaTime internally
                        m_CurrentTurnAmount = desiredTurnAmount;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    m_CurrentTurnAmount = 1;
                }
                m_LastFlatAngle = currentFlatAngle;
            }

            // camera position moves towards target position:
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, m_Target.position, deltaTime*m_MoveSpeed);

            // camera's rotation is split into two parts, which can have independend speed settings:
            // rotating towards the target's forward direction (which encompasses its 'yaw' and 'pitch')
            if (!m_FollowTilt)
            {
                targetForward.y = 0;
                if (targetForward.sqrMagnitude < float.Epsilon)
                {
                    targetForward = transform.forward;
                }
            }
            var rollRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetForward, m_RollUp);

            // and aligning with the target object's up direction (i.e. its 'roll')
            m_RollUp = m_RollSpeed > 0 ? Vector3.Slerp(m_RollUp, targetUp, m_RollSpeed*deltaTime) : Vector3.up;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rollRotation, m_TurnSpeed*m_CurrentTurnAmount*deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

[This are the cars that the map gets from the selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz4Z2.jpg)

[This is the follow cam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgdPC.jpg)

[This is what happens when the player chooses the car, it switches places with an empty object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tECLf.jpg)

[The only way to follow is if I go in the editor and manually drag the car into the follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyIEu.jpg)

Edit: I found a way to work around it, anyone wondering you just have to make a prefab with the car and camera.

Comment: I suggest you to use **Cinemachine** for this. You can make a very comfortable setting with **VirtualCamera**. Smooth transitions, distance tracking, rotation tracking etc. Everything is pretty easy. https://unity.com/unity/features/editor/art-and-design/cinemachine